# How do i restrict a user accessing my site other than office which has got many branches

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, networking

I have a site where i need to restrict users from downloading the data when accessed from outside office. Office may be one or more. I have setting cookie in my mind. But i am not sure if its safer method. The computer cannot be identified with static IP. Is there any other method?

Comment: Noope you cnt do ,better you can use login system for it...??

Comment: i have a login system. But i dont want that user to download data from outside other than office

Comment: You could perhaps use the IP address of the office's router (if it's a static IP address), if the addresses are the same then allow access to an alternative/secure page, otherwise deny. But this might be better asked/looked-into over on [SF].

Comment: Then you can use office IP address for that....

Comment: Ok understand ....orelse you can use routers..??

Comment: Then you will need to server your files from an internal IP in your office and those will 404 from an external source

Comment: the problem is that the office which i am referring to, we don't have any access rights.. there are lots of office we just give our url and login details.. its something like a franchise

Answer (score 1):

you can use .htaccess rule and add your office multiple IP

for example.

```
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.100\.110\.175
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.106\.2\.36
 RewriteRule $ http://www.redirectdomain.net [R=301,L]
```